# Execute code on Google Drive upload

Tags: php, cron, google-drive-api

Each time a file is uploaded in a specific Google Drive folder, I would like to create a new entry in my CRM.

Since I'm using PHP, I think I might have to run a cron to check for the new files in Google Drive, then report them into my CRM.

But I was wondering, is there a way to tell Google to run my script each time a file is uploaded into a specific folder, thus avoiding the use of crons?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's very unlikely that google will call out to your CRM. Have you searched the SDK for events fired?

Comment: Thank you @AndréSchild, I could not find anything on Google before you gave me the right words :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Google provides a push notification system.
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push

I still have to test it, but if there is a solution to my problem I think it's this feature ;-)

Thanks to @AndréSchild for his help.